# Opening third party links in the same tab

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

Where I work, we have a third party application that is used to open links to some of our various internal sites. Someone has made a request of that every time this application opens a link to one of our CRM applications, it reuse the an open tab. I'm able to write some javascript that can reload content in the same tab, but the request here is to keep using the same tab over and over.  However, IE is configured to open links from third party programs in a new tab. I get the sense what this individual is asking me is impossible, but I want to make sure, since he claims this was done with Salesforce.

Comment: Have you considered iframes? you might be able to have a tab is essentially an iframe and then set the source over & over again via JS.

Comment: I did try that solution, but IE keeps opening the link in a new tab.